# Handling the Check Box filter in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im Having a Table which has multiple records and Filter component with the Search Bar. What im trying to do is Based on the value selected by the user from all the filters i have pass those arrays to parent and form an object,

Im having 3 components here,

1)Parent : Data

```
export default function Data(props) {

  const [domain, setDomain] = useState([]);
  const [fileType, setFileType] = useState([]);
  const [entity, setEntity] = useState(["Patents"]);
  const [year, setYear] = useState({});
 //This is the search bar state
  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);


//based on the filter values im calling the API to get the records for table based on the value selected by the user from my filer
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchResults = async (projectid) => {
      const url = props.apiURL.rpaapiurl + "/search";

      console.log("fetchData called-->" + url);

      const resultsObj = {
        projectId: projectid,
        filter: {
          domain: domain,
          fileType: fileType,
          entity: entity,

        },
      };

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(resultsObj),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("All data-->", data);
      setResults(data);
    };
    fetchResults(5);
  }, [domain, fileType, entity]);


const handleFileType = (fileTypeArray) => {
    setFileType(fileTypeArray);
  };

return (

<Item1>
        <Dropdown onChangeFileType={(FileTypeFilteredArray) => handleFileType(FileTypeFilteredArray)} ></Dropdown>
</Item1>

<Item2>
            <Table
              Data={dataresults}
              Attributes={resultTable}
              entitytypeHandler={props.entitytypeHandler}
            ></Table>
</Item2>

)
```

From the data parent component im passing the hadler which will return updated array from the child and im setting it to state.

2)Child : Dropdown

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
  return (
<FilterItem>
            <Input
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search in title, description, keywords"
            ></Input>
         
            <Filter1></Filter1>
            
            <Filetr2></Filetr2>
            
            <ContentFormat
              onChangeFileType={props.onChangeFileType}
            ></ContentFormat>
           
            <Filter4></Filter4>
           
            <Filter5></Filter5>
            <TextWrap>
              <P text="End year" fontSize="14px" color="#454545"></P>
              <KeywordImg src={droparrow} />
            </TextWrap>

          </FilterItem>
)}
```

Nothing special here since we can not skip a component passing the same thing to nested child,

3. Nested Child : ContentFormat

```
export default function ContentFormat(props) {
  const [isDisplay, setIsDisplay] = useState("false");
  const array = ["HTML", "PDF"];

const toggle = () => {
    setIsDisplay(!isDisplay);
  };
  
  let fileTypeArray = [];

  const handleSelection = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log("value-->", +value);

    if (event.target.checked == true) {
      fileTypeArray.push(value);
      console.log("if fileTypeArray-->", fileTypeArray);
    } else if (fileTypeArray.length > 0) {
      fileTypeArray = fileTypeArray.filter((element) => {
        console.log("element-->", +element);
        if (event.target.value !== element) return element;
      });
      console.log("else fileTypeArray-->", fileTypeArray);
     
    }

    console.log("function fileTypeArray-->", fileTypeArray);
  };

const applyClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("Applied fileTypeArray-->", fileTypeArray);
    props.onChangeFileType(fileTypeArray);
  };

return (
    <div>
      <DropContent>
        <DropButton onClick={toggle}>
          {" "}
          <P text="By Content Format" fontSize="14px" color="#454545"></P>
          <KeywordImg src={droparrow} />
        </DropButton>
        <ContextWrapper style={{ display: isDisplay ? "none" : "block" }}>
          <P
            text="Filter by Extension types"
            fontSize="18px"
            color="#ACACAC"
            textAlign="center"
            padding="22px 32px 14px"
          ></P>
          <DropScroll className="sl-style-3">
            {array.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <ContextItem key={index}>
                  <DropList
                    onHandleSelection={handleSelection}
                    text={item}
                    value={item}
                  ></DropList>
                </ContextItem>
              );
            })}
</DropScroll>
          <ApplyButton onClick={applyClickHandler}>
            <P text="Apply" fontSize="16px" color="#fff" textAlign="center"></P>
          </ApplyButton>
        </ContextWrapper>
      </DropContent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

4)DropList

```
export default function DropList(props) {
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    props.onHandleSelection(e);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="">
        <TickBox
          type="checkbox"
          id={props.id}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            changeHandler(e);
          }}
        />
        {props.text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting the updated array on click of apply button in the parent but if user un-selects any check box the it deleting the complete array

In data i have to form the object base on the state array passed by all the filters, i tried for the one filter as above but its not working can any one suggest better way to do it,

Because here handling one filter is default and i have to do it for total 5 filters

So any suggestion or one common component for all the filters

Im not sure whether i should be asking these kinda questions or not since I'm very at posting the right questios but pardon me if its wrong question or the way of asking is wrong,

Any help would be appricited.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on codesandbox? Current code missing some component libraries used.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar can you please tell me what im missing here, ill add here only, because it wont be possible for me to public the complete code, i hope you can understand.

Comment: You can prepare a sample code not asking to put the original code to reproduce the issue. So someone can have look at the running code and give you the solution.